# 'Unsupported Browser' response for DWR Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jmeter, dwr

I have a jmeter script which has some DWR Ajax requests.
When I execute this script, I am seeing the below response for all the DWR Ajax requests:

```
//<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Error. This may be due to an unsupported browser.\nSee the mailing lists at http://www.getahead.ltd.uk/dwr/ for more information.');
//</script>
```

I would greatly appreciate if anybody could help me in getting this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you don't provide a "real-life" User-Agent string header with the request.

You need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) config element to send `User-Agent` header with correct line of one of supported browsers.

For instance, mine Firefox 26 is follows:

`User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0`

Comment: I used this user agent, but still the problem persists.